# Parse MegaCLI output using BASH

Tags: bash

I am dumping the complete configuration output of my 2 RAID controllers using LSI's MegaCLI command.  I would like to parse the text file and print out only the lines I am interested in.  For example:

```
"Adapter" 
"Product Name" 
"RAID Level Size State" 
"Number Of Drives" 
"Physical Disk" 
"Raw Size"
"Link Speed" 
"Media Type" 
"Drive Temperature"
```

However, given the fact that the file contains configuration data for 2 RAID controller cards in descending order, how would I best approach this task using ONLY BASH!  Below is the output I am dealing with.

**NOTE**: I should mention that I plan on installing another RAID controller soon, so ideally I would want to use something like BASH's 'read' built-in to read in the file. That way, the script will automatically catch a newly installed RAID controllers config data.

```
==============================================================================
Adapter: 0
Product Name: Supermicro SMC2208
Memory: 1024MB
BBU: Absent
Serial No:
==============================================================================
Number of DISK GROUPS: 1

DISK GROUP: 0
Number of Spans: 1
SPAN: 0
Span Reference: 0x00
Number of PDs: 2
Number of VDs: 1
Number of dedicated Hotspares: 0
Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 54.947 GB
Sector Size         : 512
Mirror Data         : 54.947 GB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 2
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Enabled
Encryption Type     : None
Bad Blocks Exist: No
PI type: No PI

Is VD Cached: No
Physical Disk Information:
Physical Disk: 0
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 0
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 5
WWN: 5001517803d94502
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 55.899 GB [0x6fccf30 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 55.399 GB [0x6eccf30 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 54.947 GB [0x6de5000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: 300i
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221103000000
Connected Port Number: 1(path0)
Inquiry Data: CVMP302300A6060AGN  INTEL SSDSC2CT060A3                     300i
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Solid State Device
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Physical Disk: 1
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 1
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 2
WWN: 5001517803d855bb
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 55.899 GB [0x6fccf30 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 55.399 GB [0x6eccf30 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 54.947 GB [0x6de5000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: 300i
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221102000000
Connected Port Number: 0(path0)
Inquiry Data: CVMP3020013L060AGN  INTEL SSDSC2CT060A3                     300i
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Solid State Device
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No


==============================================================================
Adapter: 1
Product Name: Supermicro SMC2208
Memory: 1024MB
BBU: Absent
Serial No:
==============================================================================
Number of DISK GROUPS: 1

DISK GROUP: 0
Number of Spans: 1
SPAN: 0
Span Reference: 0x00
Number of PDs: 2
Number of VDs: 1
Number of dedicated Hotspares: 0
Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 54.947 GB
Sector Size         : 512
Mirror Data         : 54.947 GB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 2
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAhead, Cached, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Enabled
Encryption Type     : None
Bad Blocks Exist: No
PI type: No PI

Is VD Cached: No
Physical Disk Information:
Physical Disk: 0
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 0
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 5
WWN: 5001517803d94502
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 55.899 GB [0x6fccf30 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 55.399 GB [0x6eccf30 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 54.947 GB [0x6de5000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: 300i
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221103000000
Connected Port Number: 1(path0)
Inquiry Data: CVMP302300A6060AGN  INTEL SSDSC2CT060A3                     300i
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Solid State Device
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Physical Disk: 1
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 1
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 2
WWN: 5001517803d855bb
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 55.899 GB [0x6fccf30 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 55.399 GB [0x6eccf30 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 54.947 GB [0x6de5000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Commissioned Spare : No
Emergency Spare : No
Device Firmware Level: 300i
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221102000000
Connected Port Number: 0(path0)
Inquiry Data: CVMP3020013L060AGN  INTEL SSDSC2CT060A3                     300i
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Solid State Device
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No


Exit Code: 0x00
```

Comment: Why are sed, awk, etc unacceptable?

Comment: I've worked with megacli before, and for lack of anything else just stored the entire output in git.  Anything interesting will show up in  a `git diff`.  I learned quite a lot about the megaraid controllers that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "ONLY BASH", do you really mean it? bash by itself is pretty powerless; it really depends on having a collection of non-builtin commands available to do anything nontrivial. Also, do you really just want the selected lines, or do you want to reformat the info at all?

If you just want the lines (and maybe a little header info) and have `egrep` available, this is simple:

```
MegaCLI -whateveroptions | egrep '^(Adapter|Product Name|RAID Level Size State|Number Of Drives|Physical Disk|Raw Size|Link Speed|Media Type|Drive Temperature):`
```

If you really need 100% pure bash, you can do it with `read`, `case`, and `echo`:

```
MegaCLI -whateveroptions | while read line; do
    case "$line" in
        Adapter:* | \
        Product Name:* | \
        RAID Level Size State:* | \
        Number Of Drives:* | \
        Physical Disk:* | \
        Raw Size:* | \
        Link Speed:* | \
        Media Type:* | \
        Drive Temperature:* )
            echo "$line" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Hey Gordan - I was mistaken when I wrote "ONLY BASH"; thank you for catching that.  I meant to say "BASH, and any other external commands".  And yes, ideally I would want to re-format the info to make it more readable (perhaps outputting it into multiple columns - like 1 column per adapter).  Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you get sick of parsing this stuff I would consider using a newer LSI controller and the StorCLI64 binary.  StorCLI is somewhat similar to MegaCLI, but allows you to append " J" to every command to have the response returned in JSON.